# Does actor/agent system make iPaaS redundant?

Tags: akka, jbossfuse, lagom, alpakka

Let's assume, that I have application, that uses Akka (possibly with Alpakka and/or Lagom).

Can I still benefit from iPaaS like Red Hat JBoss Fuse?

If yes, what is that benefit?
If no, that how is called part of actor system that is an alternative to iPaaS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, actor system or [actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) is just a computational model for concurrent and asynchronous programming. This computational model per se does not solve any real problems, like object-orientation or functional programming does not. If you want to apply the actor system to solve your integration problems, what matters most would be connectivity to a variety of systems and support for the best practice documented as the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/toc.html) (EIP).

If my understanding is correct, Akka itself is just an implementation of the actor model and does not provide a wide variety of out-of-the-box connectors. Akka historically relied on Akka-Camel module (Apache Camel is the core integration engine loaded in JBoss Fuse) but recently replaced its functionality with Alpakka. So what you really need to compare is Alpakka and Apache Camel.

In terms of connectivities, Alpakka seems to be still under development; at this moment, it only provides about two dozens of connectors.
https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.14/connectors.html
On the other hand, Apache Camel is an established framework in this regard, and 280+ connectors (= "components") are already available.
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.20.0/components/readme.adoc

When it comes to EIP support, both should cover most of the patterns. One thing I would like to highlight here, however, is that for Alpakka the EIP support seems to be more barebones; it may be mostly straightforward, but essentially you still need to find your way to implement a pattern using Akka Streams DSL, as follows:
https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.14/patterns.html
In contrast, Apache Camel provides a built-in DSL for using EIP, which makes usages of the patterns more straightforward and visually recognisable:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.20.0/camel-core/readme-eip.adoc
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.20.0/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc

Provided all the information, it is up to you which technologies you choose for your integration solutions. I am sure there are other aspects to consider, such as preferences to a certain language (Scala over Java) and so on. And as Alpakka is a relatively new framework, it will evolve and the comparisons may not be valid in the future. (Apache Camel is actively evolving in the meantime, though.)

*NOTE: I am an Apache Camel contributor, so this answer may be biased toward Apache Camel. But I tried to be as factual and objective as possible to write it.*